# R caret: train() failed for repeatedcv with factor predictors

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, party

The following function shall be used with Caret's `train()` function. Without any factor variables or without cross-validation it works fine.
The problems appear when using factors as predictors and `repeatedcv`, because in the folds not all the factors are present but still appear within the factor levels:

Consider the following adapted cforest model (from the package `partykit`):

```
cforest_partykit <- list(label = "Conditional Inference Random Forest with partykit",
          library = c("partykit", "party"),
          loop = NULL,
          type = c("Classification", "Regression"),
          parameters = data.frame(parameter = 'mtry',
                                  class = 'numeric',
                                  label = "#Randomly Selected Predictors"),
          grid = function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid"){
            if(search == "grid") {
              out <- data.frame(mtry = caret::var_seq(p = ncol(x), 
                                                      classification = is.factor(y), 
                                                      len = len))
            } else {
              out <- data.frame(mtry = unique(sample(1:ncol(x), replace = TRUE, size = len)))
            }
            out
          },
          fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) {
            
             # make consistent factor levels
                if(any(sapply(x, is.factor))){                      
                  fac_col_names <- names(grep("factor", sapply(x, class), value=TRUE))
                  # assign present levels to each subset
                  for (i in 1:length(fac_col_names)) {                        
                    x[, which(names(x) == fac_col_names[i])] <- factor(x[, which(names(x) == fac_col_names[i])], 
                                                                       levels = as.character(unique(x[, which(names(x) == fac_col_names[i])])))                       
                  }              
                }
                 

            dat <- if(is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
            dat$.outcome <- y
            theDots <- list(...)
            
            if(any(names(theDots) == "mtry")) # # change controls to mtry?
            {
              theDots$mtry <- as.integer(param$mtry) # remove gtcrl 
              theDots$mtry
              theDots$mtry <- NULL
              
            } else mtry <- min(param$mtry, ncol(x))
            
            ## pass in any model weights
            if(!is.null(wts)) theDots$weights <- wts
            
            modelArgs <- c(list(formula = as.formula(.outcome ~ .),
                                data = dat,
                                mtry = mtry), # change controls to mtry?
                           theDots)
            
            out <- do.call(partykit::cforest, modelArgs)
            out
          },
          predict = function(modelFit, newdata = NULL, submodels = NULL) {
            if(!is.null(newdata) && !is.data.frame(newdata)) newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

            # make consistent factor levels
                if(any(sapply(newdata, is.factor))){                      
                  fac_col_names <- names(grep("factor", sapply(newdata, class), value=TRUE))
                  # assign present levels to each subset
                  for (i in 1:length(fac_col_names)) {                       
                    newdata[, which(names(newdata) == fac_col_names[i])] <- factor(newdata[, which(names(newdata) == fac_col_names[i])], 
                                                                       levels = as.character(unique(newdata[, which(names(newdata) == fac_col_names[i])])))                      
                  }                     
                }
                

            ## party builds the levels into the model object, so I'm
            ## going to assume that all the levels will be passed to
            ## the output
            out <- partykit:::predict.cforest(modelFit, newdata = newdata, OOB = TRUE) # predict_party, id?
            if(is.matrix(out)) out <- out[,1]
            if(!is.null(modelFit$'(response)')) out <- as.character(out) #  if(!is.null(modelFit@responses@levels$.outcome)) out <- as.character(out)
            
            out
          },
          prob = function(modelFit, newdata = NULL, submodels = NULL) { # submodels ?
            if(!is.null(newdata) && !is.data.frame(newdata)) newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
            obsLevels <- levels(modelFit$'(response)')
            rawProbs <- partykit::predict.cforest(modelFit, newdata = newdata, OOB = TRUE) # predict(, type="prob) ? id?
            probMatrix <- matrix(unlist(rawProbs), ncol = length(obsLevels), byrow = TRUE)
            out <- data.frame(probMatrix)
            colnames(out) <- obsLevels
            rownames(out) <- NULL
            out
          },
          predictors = function(x, ...) {
            vi <- partykit::varimp(x, ...)
            names(vi)[vi != 0]
          },
          varImp = function(object, ...) {
            variableImp <- partykit::varimp(object, ...)
            out <- data.frame(Overall = variableImp)
            out
          },
          tags = c("Random Forest", "Ensemble Model", "Bagging", "Implicit Feature Selection", "Accepts Case Weights"),
          levels = function(x) levels(x@data@get("response")[,1]),
          sort = function(x) x[order(x[,1]),],
          oob = function(x) {
            obs <- x@data@get("response")[,1]
            pred <- partykit:::predict.cforest(x, OOB = TRUE, newdata = NULL)
            postResample(pred, obs)
          })
```

When applying it within train and repeatedcv using a data frame with a factor predictor variable, an error occurs:

```
library(caret)
library(party)
library(partykit)

dat <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)[1:20,]
dat$class <- as.factor(rep(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 20)], each=1))

# specifiy folds with CreateMultiFolds
set.seed(43, kind = "Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind = "Inversion")
folds_train <- caret::createMultiFolds(y = dat$weight,
                                   k = 3,   
                                   times = 2)

# specifiy trainControl for tuning mtry and with specified folds
finalcontrol <- caret::trainControl(search = "grid", method = "repeatedcv", number = 3, repeats = 2, 
                                    index = folds_train, 
                                    savePred = T)

preds <- dat[,2:5]
response <- dat[,1]

# tune hyperparameter mtry and build final model
tunegrid <- expand.grid(mtry=c(1,2,3,4)) 
#set.seed(42, kind = "Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind = "Inversion")
model <- caret::train(x = preds, # predictors
                      y = response, # response
                      method = cforest_partykit,
                      metric = "RMSE", 
                      tuneGrid = tunegrid, 
                      trControl = finalcontrol,
                      ntree = 150)
```

`warnings()`

`1: predictions failed for Fold1.Rep1: mtry=1 Error in model.frame.default(object$predictf, data = newdata, na.action = na.pass, : factor class has new levels a, c, g, k, m, p, s, t`

The aim is to identify the levels of each fold.rep and assign only those, which are present in the respective fold:

```
for (i in 1:length(folds_train)) {

  preds_temp <- preds[folds_train[[i]],]
  # check levels 
  levels(preds_temp$class)
  # which are actually present
  unique(preds_temp$class)
  # assign present levels to each subset
  preds_temp$class <- factor(preds_temp$class, levels = as.character(unique(preds_temp$class)))

}
```

I tried to include the assignment of the right factor levels within the `cforest_partykit` function (`# make consistent factor levels`), but it seems to have no effect.

How could I implement this in the caret `train()` or `trainControl()` or `createDataPartition()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure `cforest_partykit` treats categorical variables appropriately, it is best to create the design matrix explicitly through the `model.matrix` command.

For example

```
# Create a formula for the model
model_formula <- as.formula("y_column ~ . -1")

# Then create the design matrix
model_train.design.matrix <- model.matrix(model_formula, data = dat)

# Add in the y-variable
model_train.design.data <- cbind(y_column = data$y_column, model_train.design.matrix)
```